# Square characters on gnome titlebar and some system settings

Tags: gnome, titlebar

I am using the GNOME Shell interface on Ubuntu 14.10. And after upgrading it, there are no words in title bar only square characters.

[image: screenshot]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

problem solved after reinstalling fonts and rebooting :

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
sudo fc-cache -fv
```