# Only squares instead of letters and numbers are displayed in my calculator and other apps in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I don't know what I did wrong in my Ubuntu 18.04 OS. For some reason some of my apps look like this:

[image: gnome-calculator]

This also happens to other gnome apps like pdf-reviewer and Logs. Window title, menu bar etc. are all blank, display only squares.

*Problem solved:
I downloaded Google Fonts, saved them in a new folder, they can be applied system-wide, but after I did some font settings using Google Fonts it didn't work. I changed the font of Interface with Tweaks-Tool, that was what causing the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Square characters on gnome titlebar and some system settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749985/square-characters-on-gnome-titlebar-and-some-system-settings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you configured a Font which does not include the necessary glyphs to display. With a look to your name... do you use a Chinese font?

Maybe changing the font will help you. (see [Font Settings Design](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/SystemSettings/Font))

Comment: Yes I have Chinese font installed and added, and did some configuration with fonts.

Comment: can you change the font (may be to one with both – Chinese and latin glyphs)?

Comment: The link you sent helps me to figure it out. Turns out it is because I downloaded google fonts and applied them on Interface. After I changed interface font back to ubuntu fonts it works fine.

Answer (score 18):

Correct font permission issues, then rebuild the font cache:

```bash
find /usr/share/fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
find ~/.fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```

Answer (score 1):

The 3 line previous answer doesn't work on 20.04, or at least didn't on mine. It looks like they moved the folder.
I used `dconf reset -f /` and just reset the desktop to default.

Comment: **Warning: This will nuke ALL settings**