# Out of nothing I have these weird symbols instead of characters

Tags: 18.04, fonts, gnome-tweak-tool

Yesterday I turned my PC on and all system fonts look like this:

[image]
[image]

Terminal looks normal.

Any way to fix this from command line? Or do I need to go nuclear and re-install Ubuntu?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I assume your Ubuntu language is **not** English. And you have probably removed some fonts that are needed to display text in your **native** (Japanese?) language.  You may try to change the *Fonts* using `gnome-tweaks`. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o

Comment: hi, my native language is Spanish. I can't really access any system conf like tweaks because all text looks like that. Is there any way to do it from cli? BTW, i haven't changed anything font related...

Comment: Did you try the command `gnome-tweaks`? I am not exactly sure whether it is the same in your version. (I am using 19.04)

Comment: I have seen this when someone tries rm'ing their entire disk. Typically happens when critical components / caches get deleted. Did you 'rm' anything critical recently? Maybe open a terminal and run 'history' to see what commands you did previously which may have triggered this.

Comment: I kind of fixed it but there are other thinks broken (like the theme). I might better re-install ubuntu. And no, I don't remember rm-ing anything, but once I was asked to do a fsck at boot, maybe that got things screwed ...