# some ubuntu apps don't display properly the font

Tags: 18.04, system-monitor

I have this strange problem in Ubuntu LTS 18.04

I opened Ubuntu System Monitor and it looks like in the picture.

I didn't do anything special ... just installing updates. I don't know which updates was...or the day that happened?

I wanted to see the using space in system monitor...and I realized that it's mess.

The same issue seems to have the calculator.

Any ideas what could cause this ?

The system is working fine...and didn't see this problem in other apps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no information in the question that can lead to any suggestion.

Comment: What info? Tell me and i will get it. I just opend the system monitor....and I don't know why it lokks like this. It seems that the font could be a problem? but why only there?

Comment: You gave no info at all. I have normal text in my SM. We can't guess what you did with your system.

Comment: I did not do anything.....only update the system.

Comment: How can i reset the config for the system-monitor ?

Comment: That's typically something you'd see with a missing font, but it's not clear to me how you could tell which one. I'm seeing the same thing, FWIW.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only squares instead of letters and numbers are displayed in my calculator and other apps in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1103560/)

Answer (score 2):

I recently resolved this problem by simply deleting all files from home/.cache/fontconfig directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you used snap, uninstall it via `sudo snap remove gnome-calculator`, and reinstall it via `sudo apt install gnome-calculator`. It should help you with this issue.