# Audacity Not Running on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: gtk, audacity, gnome-calculator

When I execute "audacity" by terminal I get the next logs and simply cannot use it:

```
efsandino@mc4-efsandino:~$ audacity
Gtk-Message: 09:00:50.299: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 09:00:50.299: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 09:00:50.300: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 09:00:50.336: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ALSA lib conf.c:3710:(snd_config_hook_load) cannot stat file/directory /usr/share/alsa/cards/aliases.conf
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.default
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.default
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.dmix
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib seq_hw.c:466:(snd_seq_hw_open) open /dev/snd/seq failed: Permission denied
Terminado (killed)
```

Any Idea about how to solve it ? - Also I've noted that my gnome-calculator shows strange simbols these problems are related ?

My OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
[image: Ubuntu Information]
[image: GNOME CALCULATOR]

Comment: I have sound, the issue is with Audacity

Comment: I doubt both issues are linked althrough the overlay may also need fonts. For the calculator it looks like a font issue answered here 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o

Comment: both issues where solved using the next command !

         sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-ubuntu-font-family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue, both issues with the re-installation of fonts as shown in the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```