# Strange Characters in Calculator UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: 18.04

[image: Strange Images in Calculator]

I think the issue is in someway related with GTK, any Ideas ?

Comment: Seems like a `fonts` issue. Maybe `apt-get install --reinstall ttf-ubuntu-font-family` and `fc-cache -f -v` may fix this ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only squares instead of letters and numbers are displayed in my calculator and other apps in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o)