# Snap version of vlc does not work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: vlc, snap, 20.04

I have both snap and apt version of VLC installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. The snap version does not open up. I click on it and nothing happens. Apt version works fine.

I tried to uninstall the snap version from the software center and reinstall it using snap install command. It installs it but still does not open up.

I also tried to install the snap version from the gnome software center, the results are the same, but now I don't have Ubuntu software center on my system anymore. It disappeared and I only have the gnome software center.

It seems it snapped it. Sorry, it really did.

Any advice where to look for any error message, becasue I don't receive any...

Snap list gives me this:

```
$ snap list
Name    Version   Rev   Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core18  20200427  1754  latest/stable  canonical✓  base
snapd   2.44.3    7264  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
vlc     3.0.10    1620  latest/stable  videolan✓   -
```

Update #1:
When I try to open it in terminal I receive the following reply:

```
bobi@bobi:~$ vlc
/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory
VLC media player 3.0.10 Vetinari (revision 3.0.10-0-g7f145afa84)
[000055e046674b10] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [50 200)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Update #2:
It turned out that none of the manually installed snap sofwares are working on my system. I also have GIMP installed.

Workaround:
Interestingly if I install the FLAT version of these sofwares, they work just fine.

One addition:
The cause might be the GPU or the GPU driver judging from the terminal message. I only have this issue on my desktop which is an Intel CPU + AMD GPU system, however the snap packages and apps work fine on my laptop which is an Intel CPU + Nvidia GPU machine.

Update #3:
I tried to remove the snap store with *sudo snap remove* command and then resintall it with *sudo snap install*. After reinstall and a just in case restart of the system I managed to install vlc snap version from the snap store however I received the same error message, which I pasted in Update #1.
If I install the snap version of vlc with the gnome software tool or in terminal, I still have the same problem.

On top of that, the snap store now also has some kind of problems displaying itself:
[image]

Comment: Same here - apt version works fine, but opening snap version in terminal returns `fopen /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/snap.vlc.vlc/cgroup.procs failed: Permission denied`. 
If Canonical wants people to use snaps, they must work flawlessly and swiftly out of the box.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday and VLC was working fine, however when I turend on the computer today morning the issue came back. I really don't have an idea why...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only squares instead of letters and numbers are displayed in my calculator and other apps in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Béné solved my issue on my other question connected to this issue!

The solution, which ALMOST worked for me can be found [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o/1178763#1178763)!

HOWEVER, the second command in the post above gave me an error message. I modified them a little bit, the following solution worked for me and remained working after a system restart.:

```
sudo find /usr/share/fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```

Comment: Great work following up and posting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should to install new version of snap store.
`sudo snap install snap-store`
And from snap-store install vlc

Comment: Sorry, didn't help. I added a third update to my original post detailing why it did not.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

```
sudo find /usr/share/fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
sudo fc-cache -r -v
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by add this command in terminal

```
   vlc -vvv
```