# Snap store does not display characters

Tags: 20.04, snap

I have issues with the snap store and with snap packages in general on Ubuntu 20.04.
My problems started when I tried to install VLC media player, which I detailed in this question:
[LINK TO POST](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235388/snap-version-of-vlc-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-20-04)

I tried to remove and reinstall the snap store with snap remove and snap install comands. After I did that my snap store kind of broke and cannot display any characters. See the screenshot below:
[image]

I receive the following error messages in terminal, when I try to open it there:

```
bobi@bobi:~$ snap-store
19:15:19:0438 Gs  enabled plugins: odrs, rewrite-resource, snap, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
19:15:19:0438 Gs  disabled plugins: appstream, desktop-categories, desktop-menu-path, dpkg, dummy, epiphany, fedora-pkgdb-collections, generic-updates, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-featured, hardcoded-popular, modalias, os-release, provenance, provenance-license, repos, shell-extensions
19:15:19:0597 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
19:15:19:0602 Gs  updates-shell: failed to get updates: no plugin could handle get-updates
19:15:19:0602 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
19:15:19:0602 Gs  failed to get system app
19:15:19:0602 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
19:15:19:0740 Gs  hiding category audio-video featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
19:15:19:0740 Gs  hiding category graphics featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
19:15:20:0309 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
19:15:20:0608 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
```

In addition to that, when I install the snap version of GIMP in terminal it also fails to load any characters during startup and once it loads it crashes. See the load screen glitch here:
[image]

And the error message here:

```
bobi@bobi:~$ gimp
/snap/gimp/273/usr/bin/gimp: Gimp-Widgets-FIGYELMEZTETÉS: parse_iso_codes: error parsing '/build/gimp/parts/gimp/install/usr/share/xml/iso-codes/iso_639.xml': No such file or directory

Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object width does not accept value [75 100)
/snap/gimp/273/usr/bin/gimp: Gimp-Text-KRITIKUS: gimp_font_factory_load_names: assertion 'fontset' failed

(gimp:7182): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 21:27:19.894: gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple: assertion 'dest_width > 0' failed

(gimp:7182): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 21:27:19.894: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:7182): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 21:27:19.894: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:7182): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 21:27:19.894: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:7182): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 21:27:19.894: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:7182): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 21:27:19.894: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels_with_length: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:7182): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 21:27:19.894: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:7182): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 21:27:19.894: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:7182): GLib-ERROR **: 21:27:19.894: ../../../../glib/gmem.c:333: overflow allocating 18446744073709551615*18446744073709551615 bytes

(script-fu:7285): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: 21:27:19.970: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error
Nyomkövetési/töréspont csapda (core készült)
```

What to do? Flathub and "old" deb version of Gimp and Vlc work fine. I guess I need to stick to those at the moment.

Comment: Rebuilding the font cache should help, as outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1178763/21008).

Comment: Thanks a lot Béné for the quick reply. That did the trick for me!!!!!

Now all the snap applications work! Snap-store, Gimp, vlc!

I copied previously the windows fonts into the usr/share/fonts/windowsfonts folder. THat might have caused the problem, however in Ubuntu 18.04 such things never occured....

Many thanks for the help again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only squares instead of letters and numbers are displayed in my calculator and other apps in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o)

Comment: @Bo55bob, glad I could help! :) Enjoy your snap apps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to update the font cache every time I restart the system! :(
So it works but makes things difficult...

Comment: I made a little bit of a workaround. I works now for me. I updated my answer with the commands I used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Béné answered the questions! Thank you!

The following solution ALMOST worked form me in [THIS POST!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o/1178763#1178763)

HOWEVER, the second command in the post above gave me an error message. I modified them a little bit, so the following solution worked for me and remained working after a system restart.:

```
sudo find /usr/share/fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```