# Ubuntu 20.04 Chromium snap fonts missing and become 'boxy'

Tags: 20.04, fonts, chromium

My fonts stop working randomly in Chromium browser

```
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
Chromium 89.0.4389.72 snap
```

It goes back to normal when I restart or log back in, but then 1 hour or 5 days later, it breaks again.

I have removed and reinstalled the Chromium snap package, rebuilt the fonts with `sudo fc-cache -r -v` but still having this issue.

Example screenshot:

[image]

I have been following the advices here:

- [Snap store does not display characters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243967/snap-store-does-not-display-characters)
- [Only squares instead of letters and numbers are displayed in my calculator and other apps in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o/1178763#1178763)

But it seems like it keeps breaking again.

Any suggestions on how to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 0):

my friend. You can try to install it in DEB form. In [this](https://www.osradar.com/install-chromium-web-browser-ubuntu-linux-mint/) post, they explain it well. Remember to change the version.

Another alternative is to use Flatpak which is explained in [this](https://www.osradar.com/install-chromium-using-flatpak/) post as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I succeeded in restarting chromium properly displaying the pages was removing all the cache. So

```
cd ~/snap/chromium/common/.cache
~/snap/chromium/common/.cache$ rm -rf *
```

Hope this can help also as a hint on what could be the problem.