App from snap is displaying boxes rather than characters
I installed Spek acoustic spectrum analyser with sudo snap install spek, however the text in the spek GUI interface is displaying in boxes. This is weird because all my other apps are displaying perfectly fine (though they are installed via apt). I did try to delete cache or ini files to reboot the front setting for snap and spek by following the answers on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04, but's nothing changed, still boxes.
When I tried to execute spek from commandline there is error printed, note dispite that the error occured, the app still successfully executed with those boxes.
$ spek
Gtk-Message: 13:47:07.128: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Debug: Failed to connect to session manager: Could not open network socket

Snap store version
snap --version
snap    2.63+24.04ubuntu0.1
snapd   2.63+24.04ubuntu0.1
series  16
ubuntu  24.04
kernel  6.8.0-38-generic

here is what happen when I rebuild font chache
sudo find /usr/share/fonts -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
sudo fc-cache -r -v
Font directories:
    /root/.local/share/fonts
    /usr/local/share/fonts
    /usr/share/fonts
    /root/.fonts
    /usr/share/fonts/X11
    /usr/share/fonts/cMap
    /usr/share/fonts/cmap
    /usr/share/fonts/opentype
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype
    /usr/share/fonts/type1
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/util
    /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-cns1
    /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-gb1
    /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan1
    /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan2
    /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-korea1
    /usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/libreoffice
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/litefonts
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/quicksand
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu
    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy
    /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts
    /usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large
/root/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 43 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: caching, new cache contents: 94 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cMap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 5 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-cns1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-gb1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan2: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-korea1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 14 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 22 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato: caching, new cache contents: 18 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation: caching, new cache contents: 16 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/libreoffice: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/litefonts: caching, new cache contents: 201 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts: caching, new cache contents: 60 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto: caching, new cache contents: 307 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/quicksand: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu: caching, new cache contents: 232 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/root/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/share/fonts/X11: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cMap: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/opentype: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/type1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-cns1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-gb1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan2: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-korea1: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/libreoffice: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/litefonts: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/quicksand: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: skipping, looped directory detected
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/root/.cache/fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
/root/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded



Please see the answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243967/snap-store-does-not-display-characters

As I said, rebuilding font cache is not working. That is why I posted this quastion, cause all the other solution I see if rebuild font cache

It seems removing fontconfig did not reset the snap, are you sure that fontconfig was removed?

Checked in sapstore,  Or Appstore spek there is not packaged in snap, it is Debian, did you download from Appstore, and which version of Ubuntu do you have? It is imprtant to see what you downloaded.

I'm using the newest Ubuntu which is Ubuntu 24.04, and I did install it from snap, here is a proof. ```snap install spek
snap "spek" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'


ok, testing now

I added the terminal output of rebuild cache to the quastion, so you can check. Seems successful
