# Calendar app text looks corrupted : Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am on Ubuntu 20.04, text for Calendar apps looks corrupted like this:

[image: Calendar app]

Tried clearing font cache using also

```
 sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Recently I installed Gnome Contacts it also has the same problem.

Comment: Is it a snap package?

Comment: You are right, its a snap package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only squares instead of letters and numbers are displayed in my calculator and other apps in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o)

Comment: I had some google fonts installed in fonts directory, removed them and rebuilt font cache.  Still same problem.