Font appearing as 'boxes' on minecraft launchers
I keep encountering this problem on my PC (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64), with Minecraft Launchers specifically Legacy Launcher and TLauncher, where i get letters being presented as boxes and I do not know how to fix it. I would appreciate it if someone provided a solution for this:
legacy launcher

TLauncher

Results of using snap list, uname -a and lsb_release -a respectively
Snap list: Snap List:
uname -a: uname -a:
lsb_release -a: [lsb_release -a:](it didnt work)5

3 suggestions, type snap list , type uname -a and type lsb_release -a in terminal, and Edit your question with the rsults. Do not write them in comments.

see if any of these https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o help, do not use the third answer.

Change your default font in font selection (change it to Ubuntu Regular)

This might be an answer but without how to make the change it is not. Also in the question the OP never says they changed the font.
