# ubuntu 20.04 LTS numbers in icons help please

Tags: icons

no letters in icons just numbers this happend after I upgraded from 18.10 to 20.04LTS - help please [screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe3jB.png)

I also tried to install Gnome-Tweaks which failed [failded install of Tweaks-Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBLRd.png)

Comment: might be same issue? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o / https://askubuntu.com/questions/749985/square-characters-on-gnome-titlebar-and-some-system-settings

Comment: thanks pLumo but i still havent got it fixed sorry im new to ubuntu i tried install Tweaks-Tool and could not install

Comment: you were not able to install gnome-tweak-tool because there is already an apt-get running ... perhaps your system-upgrade, or the unattended-upgrade running in the background --- anyways i don think gnome-tweak-tool will help you much with xfce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay according to the images you are running xfce-desktop, and you might have used some (special) fonts that got deleted after the upgrade, or in some other way the settings got messed up.

a quick and dirty solution would be to delete them and then let xfcond reset them to the standard - all commands executed in the terminal:

1. let's stop xconfd: `pkill xfconfd`
2. delete the settings `rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/`
3. restart xfconfd: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd`

after that the issue should be solved ;)

Comment: @edd so than please mark it as solved via tick under neath the vote counter to the left of the answer; and while you at it an upvote might be nice too ;)